# maxquant error: Unhandled Exception: System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array

Tags: maxquant

An error occurred while I was running the program maxquant (2.0.3):

Reading search engine results (SP)

Unhandled Exception:
System.Exception: Exception during execution of external process: 1228404
Unhandled Exception:
System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
at MsLib.Search.AndromedaPeptide.FromString (System.String line, BaseLibS.Ms.Data.Protein.ProteinSet proteinSet) [0x000a9] in :0
at MsLib.Search.AndromedaQuerySp.Add (System.Int32 count, System.String line, BaseLibS.Ms.Data.Protein.ProteinSet proteinSet, System.Int32 minLength) [0x00001] in :0

[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
at MsLib.Search.AndromedaPeptide.FromString (System.String line, BaseLibS.Ms.Data.Protein.ProteinSet proteinSet) [0x000a9] in :0

how can i fix it, thank your very much!

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I only changed the modification and added the fasta  raw file  in the configuration file, Other parameters were default.

Comment: Dear @jingzhao thanks for posting back. Could you kindly "accept" your answer (green tick button) - it does help with our site stats

Answer (score 1):

****this was the xml file that i configured to maxquant. i changed modification and added the fastq and raw file. Other parameters were default. however, 'Unhandled Exception: System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array' was reported when I run the command '*maquant mq.xml*'. but, When I only kept the N modification, the program ran successfully, but a small amount of peptides were identified.
[image]
[image]